# Correction Layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm doing another art piece and a couple of artists recommended instead of making skin colors as shapes with the pen tool as a base I should make a correction layer. I googled correction layer but the first thing it said was adjustment and fill layers. What is and how can I make a correction layer?

Comment: Adjustment layer == "correction" layer.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a Filter to a Smart Object Layer.

Adjustment Layers get created and applied to the Smart Object when the filter is selected.

A Correction Layer would be the use of an Adjustment layer to correct the effects of the filter applied to the object.

Adjustment layers allow for "small adjustments" These are non destructive, and amendable (can be switched on/ off, increased or decreased).

[Create a Smart Object](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/102077/im-looking-for-hierarchy-dependent-logo-version-management/102078#102078) from your layer, or use an existing smart object.